# Unable to set success message from helper & Observer in 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, helper

I have an observer for

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

which will call the method :

```
sendSmsOnSuccess()
```

**The method is as follows :**

```
public function sendSmsOnSuccess($observer)
{
    if($order->getStatus()== ($this->ORDER_STATUS_COMPLETE) || $order->getStatus()== ($this->ORDER_STATUS_PROCESSING))
    {
      if(!$this->sandbox){
            $helper->prepareSmsData($orderid);
        }
    }
}
```

**The prepareSmsData method :**

```
public function prepareSmsData($orderid,$showAlert=false)
{
  // after some processing the data 
 return($this->sendSms($sms_text,$customerData->getTelephone(),$showAlert));
}
```

**The sendSms Method**

```
private function sendSms($text,$gsm_num,$showAlert)
{
   if(!Mage::registry('messageDisplayed')){ 
   Mage::register('messageDisplayed',true); 
   $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session'); 
   $message = 'Coupon code & Redeem code sent to your mobile number ('.$gsm_num.')';
   $session->addSuccess($message);
    if($showAlert)
          {
              echo('<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Message sent to Mobile Number");
                    window.close();
              </script>');
          }
   }
}
```

The problem is : the successMessage is never displayed on frontend, if i var_dump($session) with in the sendSms method, i can see the success message. i tried to display successMessage even from the Observer.php. but not showing at all

Answer (score 0):

*There are small modification needed at  your code:*

***checkout_onepage_controller_success_action*** event give **`only  array of order ids`** `order_ids`.

[***`Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));`***](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php#L294)

You cannot get ***directly Order object from Observer***  for this event,you need  call `sales/order` model by those ids

```
public function sendSmsOnSuccess($observer)
{
    $order_ids=$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    if(!is_array($order_ids)):
        return;
    endif;

        foreach ($order_ids as $eachOrderId) {

            $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($eachOrderId);   
            if($order->getStatus()== ($this->ORDER_STATUS_COMPLETE) || $order->getStatus()== ($this->ORDER_STATUS_PROCESSING))
            {
              if(!$this->sandbox){
                    $helper->prepareSmsData($orderid);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: still not working, :( & why should i use foreach  since there will be only one orderid ?

Comment: I tried Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess('Blah Blah Blah'); inside sendSmsOnSuccess() method by commenting all other lines. still not showing